# Function as a parameter

Tags: scala

I have a few functions with a same coding pattern:

```
def updateFooValidationStatus(fooId: Long, user: String, valid: Boolean): Option[Foo] = {

  val fooMaybe = fooDao.getFooById(activityId)
  fooMaybe match {
    case Some(foo) => {
      fooDao.update(foo.copy(updatedBy = Some(user),
        validationStatus = if (valid) Some(DataEntryValidationStatus.Valid) else Some(DataEntryValidationStatus.Invalid))
    )
   }
   case None =>
    throw new DomainException(s"Foo with ID: '$fooId' doesn't exist")
  }
}
```

To make my code less repeated, I write a new private function as

```
private def updateDomainObjectValidationStatus(f1: Long => Option[DomainObject],
               parameter1: Long,
               f2: DomainObject => Option[DomainObject],
               paramter2: String,
               valid: Boolean ): Option[DomainObject] ={

  val somethingMaybe = f1(parameter1)
  somethingMaybe match {
    case Some(something) =>
      f2(
        something.copyMe(updatedBy = Some(paramter2),
        validationStatus = if(valid) Some(DataEntryValidationStatus.Valid) else Some(DataEntryValidationStatus.Invalid))
      )
    case None =>
      throw new DomainException(s"Object with ID: '$parameter1' doesn't exist")
  }
}
```

where

```
trait DomainObject { ... }

case class Foo( ... ) extends DomainObject { ... }
```

With the above changes, I, however, can't call updateDomainObjectValidationStatus inside of updateFooValidationStatus due to an error on one parameter

```
type mismatch, expected (DomainObject) => Option[DomainObject], actual (Foo) => Option[Foo]
```

Interestingly, it doesn't complain the first parameter

```
(Long) => Option[DomainObject]
```

which takes

```
(Long) => Option[Foo]
```

What will be a code design in the Scala idiomatically fashion to make the above code works?

Comment: `def`s are not functions, they are methods

Answer (score 4):

What happens here is: `updateDomainObjectValidationStatus` can't accept a value with type `(Foo) => Option[Foo]` as an argument of type `(DomainObject) => Option[DomainObject]`, because **functions are *contravariant* in their argument type(s) and *covariant* in their return type**. What does that mean?

- If `A` extends `B` then a function *returning* `A` extends a function returning `B` (that's why compiler doesn't complain about your first parameter)
- However, if `A` extends `B`, then a function with *argument* of type `B` extends a function with argument of type `A` - meaning, the other way around!

Why does that make sense?

Think about it: if `A extends B`, we can say "A is a B". Now, "a function on A" can work on any `A`, but not necessarily on any `B`, right? If your function has an `Int` argument, you can't pass a value with `AnyVal` type... The opposite does work - a function on `AnyVal` can definitely be called with an `Int`.

To fix this - in this case, looks like the best approach would be to give `updateDomainObjectValidationStatus` a *type* that extends `DomainObject`:

```
private def updateDomainObjectValidationStatus[T <: DomainObject](
   f1: Long => Option[T],
   parameter1: Long,
   f2: T => Option[T],
   paramter2: String,
   valid: Boolean): Option[T] = { ... }
```

When you call it with a first parameter of type `(Long) => Option[Foo]`, the type `T` is inferred to be `Foo`, and then compiler expects `(Foo) => Option[Foo]` for the third, as expected. You even get a nice bonus - the return type would then be more specific: `Option[Foo]` instead of `Option[DomainObject]`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation. For the change, I need to parameterize the DomainObject trait as well as its sub case classes. There is a method signature defined in the trait. I need to work its out after quite few fixes.